# Module alteration in prestashop 1.5

Tags: module, prestashop

I need to alter a topseller module in the way that it would display NEW products instead of TOP SALE products, all other things being equal.
Is this feasible with less efforts or it would demand strong php skills? Could anyone share any advice on how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, why are you want to modify the blockbestsellers module? The simplest way is modify position of blocknewproducts module.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the New Products block instead of Top Sale?

Untested but it should work, you can also alter the blockbestsellers.php and replace this line:

```
$bestsellers = ProductSale::getBestSalesLight((int)($params['cookie']->id_lang), 0, 4);
```

with this:

```
$bestsellers = Product::getNewProducts((int)($params['cookie']->id_lang), 0, (int)(Configuration::get('NEW_PRODUCTS_NBR')));
```

This is the code for taking the new products